# What is WOPI Action URL?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, ms-wopi

I am currently implementing WOPI in my project using JAVA and JS. My host page is working now. I used the code from https://github.com/ethendev/wopihost.

But now I am facing the problem with action URL currently I am using https://word-view.officeapps.live.com/wv/wordviewerframe.aspx?WOPISrc=MyFileURL&access_token=DASDASAS for word files. This URL always returns server unavailable.

Is there any possibility to use my URL instead of above mentioned? My current server is UBUNTU 16.04.

Or can anyone please explain what is WOPI action URL? How to create one for my implementation in JAVA and JSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you are using (`https://word-view.officeapps.live.com/...`) can only be used for  Office Online integration, this kind of integration can only be done if you are a member of the [Office 365 - Cloud Storage Partner Program](https://dev.office.com/programs/officecloudstorage).

If you're not member of that program, you need to deploy Office Online Server (used to be known as Office Web Apps) locally. The OOS is available via [MSDN downloads](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Office%20Online%20Server%20(Last%20updated%20November%202017)).

Once deployed, the action URL can be retrieved by accessing the discovery URL - `http://your_oos/hosting/discovery`. The URL will return a discovery XML file with all available action URLs for all supported Office formats.

Comment: I found the resolution in official docs of WOPI as Microsoft is strict about end point URL so the url of the file has to be wopi/files where I was using wopi/file.